# Term by term differentiation of (bounded) operator exponential

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

By defining $$e^{A} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}A^k$$ for any $A \in \{\text{"bounded operators on Hilbert space"}\}$, apparently it is valid to take the derivative of the map $$t\mapsto e^{tA}$$ (where $t\in \mathbb{R}$) via term by term differentiation in the series. I do not see why this is valid.

I am aware of a similar notion where $A$ is instead a matrix, and the validity of term by term differentiation is easier to see in this case as each entry of $e^{tA}$ is just some usual power series in $t$.

---- Update ----

I realize that the explanation of my concern is not precise enough so I will  say more in this update. The definition of derivative of any operator valued map $\sigma: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathcal{B(H)}$ (where $\mathcal{B(H)}$ denotes space of bounded operators on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$) is, if exists, given by the familiar limit. Namely,
$$\frac{d}{dt}\sigma(t) := \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sigma(t+h)-\sigma(t)}{h}$$
computed in the operator-norm topology. So in principle one should be able to compute the derivative of $t\mapsto e^{tA}$ and $t \mapsto \frac{t^k}{k!}A^k$ using this definition. What I do not understand is the validity in the following formula\proposition
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!}A^k\right) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{d}{dt}\frac{t^k}{k!}A^k\right)$$

How do you show this?
Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Hi! Can you explain why you think the derivative of $t\mapsto e^{tA}$ is not well-defined where $A$ is an operator on Hilbert space?

Comment: @ChongxuRen Hi! I have edited the post to hopefully rectify my lack of precision. Could you please give it another look.

Comment: This is essentially because of the (locally) uniform convergence of the derivative of partial sums, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_differentiability). Although the theorem stated there mainly concerns $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions, the proof applies *mutatis mutandis* to functions taking values in Banach spaces.

Comment: @SangchulLee Hello, I am aware of that theorem. It's Theorem 7.17 of Rudin's Principle of Mathematical Analysis. The proof utilizes Mean Value Theorem, so I am not sure how you can mimic the proof as there is no Mean Value Theorem for functions taking values in Banach space...

Comment: @BernieH, That is a good point, and sorry for the confusion. I think the proof that I was thinking actually assumes not just differentiability but also the continuity of the derivative. But a even better news is that the relevant result for power series is much more straightforward. I will try to provide a proof in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of power series, most of the results in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ readily extends with due modifications. For example, let

$$ f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n z^n $$

be a power series in $z \in \mathbb{C}$, where $A_n$'s lie in a Banach space $(\mathscr{X}, \|\cdot\|)$. If we let

$$ R = \frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty} \|A_n\|^{1/n}} \in [0, \infty], $$

then it is clear that the series converges absolutely if $|z| < R$ and diverges if $|z| > R$. That is, this $R$ is precisely the radius of convergence for $f(z)$. It is also easy to check that

$$ g(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n A_n z^{n-1} $$

has the same radius of convergence as $f(z)$.

Now suppose $|z| < R$, and fix $r$ so that $|z| < r < R$. Also, consider any $h$ with $0 < |h| < r-|z|$. Then by using the identity

\begin{align*}
\frac{(z+h)^n - z^n}{h} - n z^{n-1}
&= n \int_{0}^{1} \bigl[ (z + ht)^{n-1} - z^{n-1} \bigr] \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= n(n-1)h \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{t} (z + hu)^{n-2}  \, \mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}t,
\end{align*}

we find that

\begin{align*}
\left| \frac{(z+h)^n - z^n}{h} - n z^{n-1} \right|
&\leq n(n-1)h \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{t} (|z| + |h|)^{n-2}  \, \mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}t \\
&= |h| \frac{n(n-1)}{2}(|z| + |h|)^{n-2}.
\end{align*}

Now by this estimate and the inequality $|z| + |h| < r$ altogether, it follows that

\begin{align*}
\left| \frac{f(z+h) - f(z)}{h} - g(z) \right|
&\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \|A_n\| \left| \frac{(z+h)^n - z^n}{h} - n z^{n-1} \right| \\
&\leq \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \|A_n\| r^{n-2} \right) |h|
\end{align*}

and therefore $f'(z)$ exists and is equal to $g(z)$.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed comment! I think I understand the gist of your argument now, but there are still several minor issues I would like to ask about. 1. Where can I read about power series with "coefficients" in Banach space? 2. I tried to use elementary inequalities to derive your last few steps but couldn't figure out how the $\frac{1}{2}$ came from, could you just add a few lines regarding this? (sorry, I am not that skilled at math)

Comment: @BernieH, For 1, I have no good expertise on this topic, but the keyword of 'analytic functions on Banach space' might possibly be the one to look up (or I hope so). But again, many of the basic results regarding operations on power series should readily extend to any Banach space or Banach algebra. For 2, I added a couple of more words, but in short, that factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ follows from the double integral $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{t} 1\,\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{2}$.